# Issue with 2 div slightly shifted

Tags: html, css

I would like to align (horizontally) 2 `<div>` (first one is up relatively to the second) but I get a slight shift between both.

**The Code (http://jsfiddle.net/8wfu3w26/2/):**

```css
#global-ui {
  position: relative;
}
#gui {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
#buttons-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  right: 0;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
#buttons {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div id="global-ui">
  <div id="gui"></div>
  <div id="buttons-wrapper">
    <div id="buttons">
      <button type="button" id="startButtonId" class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="13">Start</button>
      <button type="button" id="resetButtonId" class="btn btn-default" tabindex="14">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I get the following result of my menu in the right top corner of `three.js` window:

[image: little space between blue box and red box]

As you can see, there is a little horizontal space between the left border of blue box and the left border of red box. They are not perfectly aligned.

On the right border side, both seem to be aligned.

I don't know where this issue could come from, maybe from the browser (I have tested it with Firefox)?

**UPDATE :**

The solution of Tawfiq Injass works but I can't get to replace `" 2 + 'px' "` by an automatic computing of border width like this :

`document.getElementById('buttons-wrapper').style.width = gui.width - parseInt(document.getElementById('gui').style.borderWidth,10) + 'px';`

Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

How can I do for getting automatically the border width of div#gui ? thanks

Comment: do you mean to say that the red box's left edge seems to be 1px more on the left side of the box than the blue box?

Comment: Seems that value added by JS is 1px extra in red box as it has width:351px; as Blue has 350px.

Thats seems to be the reason for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you get this effect because you use JavaScript to calculate and set the Width of the red box

in this line

```
document.getElementById('buttons-wrapper').style.width = gui.width + 'px';
```

you need to compensate for the border width since your border is 2px this line need to be

```
document.getElementById('buttons-wrapper').style.width = gui.width-2 + 'px';
```

and use this code to get border Width dynamically using JavaScript

```
var box = document.getElementById('buttons-wrapper');
var borderWidth = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(box,null).getPropertyValue("border-left-width").replace("px",""));
```

check this plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/PKjEKBEC0lyjWUoSmHQ1?p=preview

Comment: your solution works but I can't get to replace " 2 + 'px' " by an automatic computing of border width like this : document.getElementById('buttons-wrapper').style.width = gui.width - parseInt(document.getElementById('gui').style.borderWidth,10) + 'px'; How can I do for getting automatically the border width of div#gui ? thanks

Comment: @user37422 you can get the border width dynamically using javascript using this code
`var box = document.getElementById('buttons-wrapper');
var borderWidth = window.getComputedStyle(box,null).getPropertyValue("border-left-width");`

Answer (score 0):

`<button>` elements default to `display: inline-block;` which tends to have that (approx) 4px space on the right side.

Try using:

```
button{
  display: block;
  float: left;
  ...
}
```

Oh and to make the wrapper fit around the buttons you'll also want to add `class="clearfix"` to the `#buttons` div.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is taken from stsckoverflow community quest

You can apply this CSS to the inner div:

```css
#inner {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

Of course, you don't have to set the width to 50%. Any width less than the containing div will work. The `margin: 0 auto` is what does the actual centering.

If you are targeting IE8+, it might be better to have this instead:

```css
#inner {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

It will make the inner element center horizontally and it works without setting a specific width.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set width for #gui and #buttons-wrapper 30% it'll fix the issue.

`#gui, #buttons-wrapper{width:30% !important;}`

[Here is link of fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8wfu3w26/5/)

**Please Note:** You can set width % as per your requirement and also can remove !important condition as it's set to override inline width.

Hope this helps you.